# DDD model issue

Tags: domain-driven-design

```
type Resource struct {
    id          string
    tenantID    string
    FieldValues map[string]interface{}
    created     time.Time
    updated     time.Time
}

type ResourceField struct {
    id        string
    tenantID  string
    name      string
    fieldType string
    created   time.Time
    updated   time.Time
}
```

I'm new on Domain driven Design and i need some help to model this in DDD with event sourcing. In this scenario the ResourceField is a global concept, i.e. is the same for all the Resource instances.

I try to model both of them as AR: ok but when i have to delete a ResourceField i have to update all the Resource instances removing from the FieldValues map the correct key. So when a ResourceField Delete command is received and performed, then an event is emitted. Now Resource listen to this event and ... the problem: i have to update all the Resources with that field ID. I have to load all the Resources, update each of them, and save the new events. But if i have thousand of thousand of Resources?

Comment: Its hard to suggest something without understanding your domain - what is `Resource` and what is `ResourceField`. Why would you delete a `ResourceField`? Can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is the #1 antipattern in DDD which is trying to create a single unified model with all data in memory. This would require a disproportionate amount of computing power.

The purpose of DDD is to model your business in a dedicated layer called domain layer. The purpose of that layer is to provide your application with code that can validate your business rules, preventing rules violation by the rest of the application. Rules violation cannot happen during query operations, as queries, by definition, do not alter the system's state. It is useful only in command operations. Also, most commands only alter a small part of the domain model, called a *context*, and you don't need to use code from other contexts when trying to validate an operation in a given use case. This is why it is paramount to model your domain layer based on command use cases, and not as a single relational model which is what you do at the persistence layer level (or equivalent).

Each context uses a model to validate rules integrity. This model is either a single entity or a structure of multiple objects, called an aggregate, among wich one is an entity and called the aggregate root. By modeling both `Resource` and `ResourceField` as aggregate roots, you place them in different contexts. This requires that your business allows the existence of each independantly: you can create a `Resource` without a `ResourceField`, and you can create a `ResourceField` without a `Resource`. But of course, DDD allows reference between two contexts, as long as you only reference data from another context to the identity property of the aggregate root entity of the other context. This means `Resource.FieldValues` can only reference `ResourceField.id`.

Now your question considers a saga which sequences two use cases:

- Delete a `ResourceField`
- Read a `Resource` which previously referenced that `ResourceField`

When implementing the domain layer for the first use case, you should not consider how the relationship reference gets updated. This is the purpose of the persistance layer, and the domain layer is persistence agnostic. The purpose of the domain layer is to validate that the command does not violate the business rules, so it should focus on cases that would prevent users from deleting the `ResourceField`. How this is implemented depends on your business rules but common examples would be to deny deleting objects with a specific state, objects with creation date older than a specific delay, etc ...

Then implementation of the reference update is delegated to the persistence layer. Depending on the architecture of your solution, both the `Resource` and the `ResourceField` contexts may share the same persistence backend (aka *single-database*) or not (aka *database-per-service*).

In a *single-database* approach, when using a relational DBMS with foreign key constraints, you can delegate that reference update to the databse engine, through usage of the `ON DELETE` clause. If using a non-foreign key reference, or a non-relational database, it is up to your persistence layer to look for and update references in other tables.

In a *database-per-service* approach, you cannot rely on the persistence layer to update the reference, because the reference is stored in the persistence store of the other context, which you do not have access to. In that situation, you need to raise an event in the `ResourceField` context, which the `Resource` context will register to. Then it is up to the `Resource` persistence layer to update references in the persistence store.

Once the reference is updated in the persistence layer, the `Resource` context will be able to query the updated state transparently.